# Map template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, syntax, member-functions

I am just confused as to what my file is supposed to look like. I am not sure on the syntax as well as how to read in the array.

Comment: You have edited out the code you had before in the first question. I suggest to bring it back. Also, let me know if the following answer was helpful.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm just confused as to what my Map.cpp file is supposed to look like.

- First of all, you can not write your template class implementation in
  a *.cpp* file. It should be all in a header file. Read the following
  for more info.
  [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)
- Secondly, there is no constructor declaration in your `Map` class
  which takes `std::string` as a parameter. Provide one!

  ```cpp
  template <typename Domain, typename Range>
  class Map
  {
  public:  
   Map(const std::string& filename);  // declare one constructor which takes std::string
      // ... other members
  };
  ```
- Thirdly, your member function definitions missing the template
  parameters.

  ```cpp
  template <typename Domain, typename Range>  // ---> this
  void Map<Domain, Range>::add(Domain d, Range r)
  {
   // implementation
  }

  template <typename Domain, typename Range>  // ---> this
  bool Map<Domain, Range>::lookup(Domain d, Range& r)
  {
   // implementation
  }
  ```
- Last but not the least, you are missing a proper destructor, which is
  essential for the `Map` class, as the allocated memory(using `new`)
  should be freed. Therefore, do accordingly the [The rule of
  three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

That being said, if you could have used [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), the manual memory management could be avoided.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename Domain, typename Range>
class Map
{
public:
    //...
private:
    // other members
    std::vector<Domain> dArray;
    std::vector<Range> rArray;
};
```

---

As a side note, avoid practising with `using namespace std;`.
[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: 4th: Why `new[]`? Why not `std::vector`? ;-) [SO: new int\[size\] vs std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9741542/7478597)

Comment: @Scheff Yeap... I am working on it. Thanks for pointing it out ;)